# how to make materializecss buttons stack nicely on small screens

Tags: css, materialize

I am doing a simple project to practice with materializecss framework, and I a have come across this problem.

The buttons when in a small screen don't stack up nicely:

[image: The buttons when in a small screen don't stack up nicely]

On a bigger screen they look good side by side:

[image]

I have this code in my index.html

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2 l6 offset-l3 xl4 offset-xl4">
        <a type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light left" >remove selected</a>
        <a class="btn waves-effect waves-light right" >remove all<i class="material-icons right">delete</i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can it be fixed using only the framework tags? I wouldn't want to create a custom CSS for it.

Comment: try adding the `type="button"` and removing the icon from the one to see if that works.

Comment: @iscmaro thnks for reminding me to add type. but still not the fix im looking  for. i am trying to make the look cansistent but if that is not possible i would like ti to stack not to be broken like that

Comment: try adding some margin to bottom of the anchor tag

Comment: try to create a grid around each button rather than around both buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2 l6 offset-l3 xl4 offset-xl4">

    <a type="button" class="col s5 btn waves-effect waves-light left" style="padding:0;">remove selected</a>

    <a class="col s5 offset-s2 btn waves-effect waves-light right" >remove all<i class="material-icons right">delete</i></a>

</div>
```

This should work nicely with mobile resolution. If you have some problem with desktop resolutions or higher then tell me here or post you whole HTML.

**EDIT:** As asked by you, the following code might help you with some things. Obviously you will have to make many changes according to your needs. But I hope that this can guide you.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12 m8 offset-m2 l6 offset-l3 xl4 offset-xl4">
        <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
        <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row hide-on-med-and-up">
    <div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2 l6 offset-l3 xl4 offset-xl4">
        <div class="row">
            <a type="button" class="col s12 btn waves-effect waves-light left" style="padding: 0;">remove selected</a>
        </div>   
        <div class="row">
            <a class="col s12 btn waves-effect waves-light right" >remove all<i class="material-icons right">delete</i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row hide-on-small-only">
    <div class="col s12 m8 offset-m2 l6 offset-l3 xl4 offset-xl4">
        <a type="button" class="col s5 btn waves-effect waves-light left" style="padding: 0;">remove selected</a>
        <a class="col s5 offset-s2 btn waves-effect waves-light right" >remove all<i class="material-icons right">delete</i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

By using `offsets` , `rows` , `container` , `grid` etc, using can achieve most of the things you want.

**But I must add**: Although by using frameworks like **materializecss**, the need for your own css is very unlikely, sometimes you might just need it.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Just one more thing I would like to add: there will always be a limit to the number of characters that a button can hold(especially in mobile view). In such cases, you might need to either shorten the button text or make the buttons take the whole width by putting col s12 in them. To give an example, the second button(Remove all) might also come below the first(Remove Selected) button. Covering the whole width... That way you can fit more text in the button.

Comment: you mean col s12

Comment: Yes. col s12. Apologies for the typo. I'm using my phone right now. Anyways, you might want to keep buttons in two rows, by giving them col s12 as property. That way you can fit more text. I hope you get it. I'll try to put it in code as well once I get back home.

Comment: But the way I'm doing in my code is also fine. It's just a tip for the future. For some cases, where the text in the button is large and because mobile phone screens are small in width, some of your text gets stripped(cut off) if you put two buttons in the same row.

Comment: i would like to add in the quest: when i make my buttons take the whole grid in small screens how would i add a space between them so that it would still look nice. using only the framework tags and classes?

Comment: @JunnelVerceluz I've added some new code in my answer. I hope it helps you.